# Disable Highlight of ui-select on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

so here is the problem :
**(all of this is in angular 1)**

I have a ui-select like below :
[image: ui-select]

Here is the code :

```
<div class="formZone-group">
    <div class="mandatory-fl">
        <div class="mandatory-field">
            <label class="control-label">{{atlasManagement.getText("#ATLAS:ATTRIBUTE")}}  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign help-icon" aria-hidden="true" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip="{{atlasManagement.getText('#ATLAS:ATTRIBUTETOOLTIP')}}" tooltip-class="customTooltip" ng-show="atlasManagement.viewManager.isActiveView(atlasManagement.constants.views.addAtlas, atlasManagement.constants.views.updateAtlas)"></i></label>
        </div>
        <div class="mandatory" ng-show="atlasManagement.viewManager.isActiveView(atlasManagement.constants.views.addAtlas, atlasManagement.constants.views.updateAtlas)">*</div>
    </div>
    <div class="select-container">
        <div class="selectPlaceHolder" ng-show="!atlasManagement.atlas.attributeIsDefined()">{{atlasManagement.getText('#ATLAS:CHOOSEATTRIBUTEPLACEHOLDER')}}</div>
        <ui-select  tagging tagging-label="false" on-select="atlasManagement.onAttributeSelected($item, $model)" ng-model="atlasManagement.atlas.attribute" theme="select2" ng-disabled="atlasManagement.viewManager.isActiveView(atlasManagement.constants.views.details)">
            <ui-select-match>{{atlasManagement.getText($select.selected.title)}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in atlasManagement.attributes | orderBy: atlasManagement.orderByFactory('title') | propsFilter: { title : $select.search }:atlasManagement.getText | orderBy: atlasManagement.orderByFactory('title')">
                <div ng-bind-html="atlasManagement.markText(atlasManagement.getText(item.title), $select.search)"></div>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to disable the highlight when i click on it...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean focus blue border?

Comment: You do realise that the focus highlight has a purpose for usability? Its bad practice to make stylistic changes that affect usability, just for appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `outline` css property ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)):

```
#myElement:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

But I'd recommend to think about it in general, maybe it's not a good idea to change this behaviour which is pretty common and standard for User (some thougths is [here](http://outlinenone.com/)).

Comment: but is it normal it highlights all of the selection instead of only one?

Comment: I would follow standard practice... anyway, this is a UX question and it requires additional research. If you do decide to kill focus border, then `outline: none` will be your weapon.